# Possible to place a widget beneath a text selection in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Any idea of how I might place a widget under a text selection in flutter?
Is it possible to get the coordinates of a piece of text or a selection?

[image: wid]

Comment: What if you split "The quick brown fox" into two widgets? or if you duplicate "The quick" text widget below :), that's probably easier than looking for stuff inside a text widget.

Comment: Possible, but then I’d have to manage highlighting

Comment: You split in three then ? :)